# Treat Salesforce VisualForce Page as an External Widget

Tags: screen-scraping, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to turn a Salesforce VisualForce Page into a widget for my corporate website. I want to access the widget using server side code and a service account. I'll cache, style, and output the widget html in my web page. I know I could just reproduce the widget with server side code and several API calls but I like the idea of being able to manage the widget in Salesforce and having the widget available for reuse elsewhere within Salesforce.

In this case, the widget is going to report on the current leaders in a contest we're tracking in Salesforce. I plan on reusing this approach for other "mini-report widgets." This is a very useful pattern. I'm sure somebody out there has elegantly solved it already. My searches have come up empty so far.

I was trying to avoid Sites because the user hitting our corporate website does not have a user account in Salesforce (now I'm thinking about a Site that allows anonymous access).

My first attempt looked like this (inspired by SSO to Self Service Portal):

```
var ws = new sfapi.SforceService();
var lr = ws.login(Secrets.salesforce_user_name, Secrets.salesforce_password);
string url = "https://na6.salesforce.com/apex/mywidget?sessionId=" + lr.sessionId;
```

I tried ?sid and ?csssid too, but urls like these just bounce me to the Salesforce login page:

```
https://na6.salesforce.com/apex/mywidget?sessionId=00D3000000myorg!my-session-id-from-logging-in-with-the-api-8_i2fX_9wnYdwnwatGVuX6jGjmVmnv50j78yfGF1aKHdoDFtIx_J9
```

I could probably use standard screen scraping techniques to post to the standard Salesforce login form with a username and password and then pull the /apex/mywidget page. But that feels clumsy and unsupported.

Now I'm thinking about making a new Site that is publicly available just to expose my widget. At least I could screen scrape that page with confidence.

Any help is appreciated. I'm going to play with the anonymous sites approach for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rendering the data into a Visualforce page, then screenscraping it seems a bit brittle, not to mention inefficient - there is a better way...

Define an Apex REST web service, then you can easily invoke that web service from your server side code, and still render it in Visualforce if you need to - you can call an Apex REST method like any other Apex method.

Here's a sample REST web service. I'm just returning a `Map<String,String>` here, but you can return any primitive type, any sObject or a List or Map of primitives or sObjects (as long as the Map has String keys) - see [the Apex REST Web Services docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_rest.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_rest.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyResource/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {
    @HttpGet
    global static Map<String,String> getResource() {
        Map<String,String> result = new Map<String,String>();

        result.put('key1', 'value1');
        result.put('key2', 'value2');

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's some PHP that calls it (I'll assume you have an access token (aka session ID) and instance URL):

```
$url = "$instance_url/services/apexrest/MyResource";
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
  array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
    "Content-type: application/json"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, ".
      "response $json_response\n");
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

echo "The service says ".$response['key1'].' '.$response['key2']."\n";

curl_close($curl);
```

And here's a Visualforce page, if you want to show the same data

```
<apex:page controller="TestRestController">
  <p>Controller says {!result}</p>
</apex:page>
```

The page controller:

```
public class TestRestController {
    public String getResult() {
        Map<String, String> result = MyRestResource.getResource();

        return result.get('key1') + ' ' + result.get('key2');
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer; this is a better way of doing things.

Comment: Now that looks first class. I'll try it out this weekend. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If it all works out, please move the checkmark to this answer, so we can promote best practice :-)

Comment: Wow! That really opened my eyes to possibilities well beyond a simple widget. But, it worked great for a widget too. Right now I'm  returning List<Contact> in XML (I set HTTP Accept to application/xml because it's easier for me to parse server-side in C#). I think I'll end up returning a single string of lightly formatted html. That way I can manipulate the presentation layer from Salesforce (desirable in my case because I'm in a dll exposed by a COM-Callable Wrapper to old school ASP--great for talking to APIs but not for presentation). Thanks for the lesson metadaddy!

Comment: Some hints for anyone taking their first look at this very worthwhile Salesforce feature. You only get one @HttpGet method and its name doesn't really matter. Your APEX class has to be at least version 22 (I struggled with this but eventually updated Force.com IDE to the latest version and opened MyClassName.cls-meta.xml in Eclipse changing the apiVersion element to 23). It's very easy in C# using WebRequest. var req = WebRequest.Create(url); req.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + sid); req.Accept = "application/xml"; req.GetResponse() and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for your purposes, but there's a URL you could try:

```
https://<endpoint host>/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=<session id>
```

Once that page has loaded, you could redirect to the widget url.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I got it working with that url. I had to share a CookieContainer between the first and second request so the authentication carried over--but it worked! I don't suppose you know if frontdoor.jsp takes a redirect param where I could do it in one request instead of two?

Comment: I tried the retURL param and I get an error message that I have to have javascript enabled (I'm using c# and HttpwebRequest). CookieCollection and two requests works well enough. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately, I tried the retURL and startURL parameters, but I couldn't get it working with those, either.

Comment: Please don't screenscrape Visualforce - there's a much better way to do this - see my answer...

Comment: Hey man can you please tell me how to get sid in js file while user login in to salesforce

Comment: @BhavikPatel your comment would probably be best put as a new question; you'd get more responses that way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Force.com Sites is exactly what you want.

The idea behind Sites is that it allows you access to Visualforce pages without having to have a login.

Comment: I think you're right when I'm willing to bite off a bigger piece of Salesforce Sites. But I'm after a "widget" in this case. Baby steps if you will. To get a widget out of sites I can IFrame it or screen scrape it--both feel clumsy. I'm going to setup a custom REST Web Service as proposed by metadaddy. Thanks though.